# Could not update ICEauthority file /home/me/.ICEauthority

Tags: boot, gnome, login

I am getting a message

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/me/.ICEauthority
```

When trying to log into Ubuntu graphically. I can log in using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

This is not a duplicate of:

[What does this startup dialog message mean "Could not update ICEauthority file"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10543/what-does-this-startup-dialog-message-mean-could-not-update-iceauthority-file)

In my case my .ICEauthority is `-rw------- 1 me me ...`

Things I tried to do to fix this:

- reset the ICE file's permissions in case something was messed up that I did not notice.
- delete the file (no new one was created)
- touch a new file after the orig was deleted
- looks like my home directory was owned by root. fixing did not help.
- .ecryptfs has correct permissions on my home directory
- autologin is off, never was turned on
- fresh install so no password changes (i'd prefer not to re-install my os because I did spend a day setting it up)
- only weirdness found was: /home/.ecryptfs/me/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase is `-rw------- 1 me root 48 .....` however that should not be an issue or so it would seem due to permissions

I installed gnome after installing the system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

I've never booted into it (or anything else rather except for tty) successfully.

Comment: Can you check the ownership of your home directory?  You may need to chown that too.

Comment: Did you try a reboot with failsafe? Might be a shot in the dark but did you turn on 'automatic login'? (a couple of releases ago that was an issue too ... turn it off and try again). command line: gksudo gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf

Comment: maybe you already did, but just in case, use chown -R on your home dir so it gets everything.

Comment: Is it possible you changed your user password recently and did not change your ecryptfs password separately?

Comment: @Mark did not do chown -r.

Comment: @Mark did not change password at all (this is a fresh install) also I can log in through terminal, would that not cause an issue if ecryptfs had a problem?

Comment: @Dmitriy.  Whether it helps this issue or not, I would definitely suggest doing `chown -R me.me /home/me` if you haven't already.  You should own everything under your $HOME.

Comment: @Mark updated my question. Did that no help.

Comment: @Dmitriy.  And yes, disregard the ecryptfs theory.  Saw something in the forums that suggested something along those lines can cause your symptom.  I think I'm out of ideas for the moment.  Good luck!

Comment: Did you try booting with the failsafe option? I ran into this when searching: http://raywoodcockslatest.blogspot.com/2010/10/ubuntu-1010-error-could-not-update.html lots of tips but I do believe you tried them all :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to re-install ubuntu. Cannot debug this. Probably gnome3 install borked it.

Comment: Hope I am not too late but did you see this topic: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742343 Gnome3 is indeed the culprit!

Comment: too late :( o well gnome2 works out of the box...

Comment: Not sure if [my case](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55568/could-not-update-iceauthority-file) is the same, but I got the same error trying to login with "gnome classic" and "Safe Mode". So maybe it's not just gnome3's issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a problem in Gnome, here is the solution, instead of uninstall and re install ubuntu, at least you can save your data backup

`sudo apt-get install lxde`

Installed  after that do Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get back to the login screen,

now select lxde in the drop down menu, entered my password, you can able to now login to an LXDE session

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I got rid of it by using the following command:

```
sudo chown user:user /home/user
```

Replace `user` with your user name.

Comment: Thanks +1 I have no idea how my home directory's owner became root.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar. ICEAuthority problem which due to the aes module can't be installed in booting, for padlock not detected, in a word, you should blacklist the padlock_aes module like:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ecryptfs.conf
blacklist padlock-aes
```

I also post [**the detailed steps**](http://lieeil.blog.com/unable-update-iceauthority-when-booting-on-unbuntu10-04-with-encrypted-home-directory/), FYI.

Comment: You cannot change the contents of a file using `cat` with the syntax you've presented. You may want to edit your question to clarify how you're suggesting people do this. There's a method that looks a little bit like what you've written, but which is syntactically different, where you run `cat >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ecryptfs.conf`, then enter `blacklist padlock-aes`, then on a new line press `Ctrl`+`D`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here is how i fixed it:

- I logged into the system as root
- deleted the user account that had the ICEauthority error (userdel user)
- I then recreated the same account only this time i used a -m switch that 
  created a home directory for the user(useradd -m user)
- I set the password to the account using this command (passwd user)
- I logged out of my root account.
- Logged in using the new account and VOILA, the no more ICEauthority problems.
- Login was Successful.
- I think the problem might have been when you created the user account, u didn't
  tell the system to create the home directory for that particular user.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, in my case my home directory owner got changed to root somehow.

changed it to my user and it worked:

```
cd /home
sudo chown user:user <homedir>
```

I did not use `-R` flag option because only the top level directory was affected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, After reading posts about using `chown` on `.ICEauthority`, I decided to try changing the Read/Write permission on the file `.ICEauthority` with `chmod`.

It was originally: `-rw-------`
So I changed it to: `-rw-rw-rw-`

And it worked! (I used `chmod 666 /home/$USER/.ICEauthority`)

Worth a try I suppose...

Comment: this is a **bad idea** - the file shouldn't have write permissions for all users. Why did you change the mode instead of the owner?