# "Could not update ICEauthority file" after login (independent of gnome)

Tags: permissions

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 64bits in my new computer, and I got this two messages after login:

[image: error 1]

and

[image: error 2]

I've tried to login with classic gnome, and safe mode, but got the same messages.

Any easy/fast solution to this? (if not I can use Ubuntu 10.10 for while)

My computer is an HP Pavilion, intel i3, 4GM ram.

Comment: Could the issue with the ICEauthority be related to encryption of your file system. Try logon with the same pw with which the file system was encrypted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a simple permissions issue.
One of two things will work:

First, try the following:

`sudo chown username:username .ICEauthority`

`sudo chmod 0644 .ICEauthority`

Change `username` to your own username (so in your situation it would be `wellington`).

If that didn't work, you'll need to (unfortunately) start with a new `/home` directory - however, ***BACK UP YOUR DATA*** before you do that. For more on backup solutions, see

- [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/2596/6005).

Comment: The `sudo chmod 0644 .ICEauthority` returned `chmod: cannot access '.IECauthority': No such file or directory`

Comment: After restarting I got the same messages. I couldn't understand why the first command worked, and on the second it says that there's no such file.. I tried removing the dot and putting a space `. IECauthority` but nothing changed. I know the file is there, as the first command worked..

Comment: @Tom Give `sudo chmod 0644 /home/<USERNAME>/.ICEauthority` a go

Comment: before I type, I got another message, now from Nautilus with permissions problems in the /home/ folder, and I remembered I used the same /home/ I was using with Fedora, so maybe there's something wrong with it.. I will re-install and format the /home/ partition. I think this will solve everything. I back here to tell.

Comment: formatting the /home partition solved =) It were problems with the /home created by Fedora.

Comment: @Tom I have had issues with `/home`'s that were created by another OS, or even an older version of Ubuntu. I'll update the answer to the solution that you used. Glad you got it solved. :)

Answer (score 9):

I managed to fix the issue by changing ownership and permissons on the folder itself, I used this:

```
sudo chown username:username /home/username
sudo chmod 700 /home/username
```

This cleared the problem right away for me.

Comment: the only that worked for me

Comment: this worked along with changing ownership for .ICEauthority

Comment: It worked buy i lost my all settings, i faced with brand new desktop. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I had today the same problem, when I moved 'Home' users folders to a different partition. I solved it, not changing permissions in '.ICEauthority' file (in fact, I deleted it), but changing the owners of that folders to their users, recursively:

```
sudo su
chown -R user /home/user
```

To do that, in login window, ALT+CTRL+F1 changes to a console. After that, ALT+CTRL+F7 returns to GUI mode. No need to reboot.

P.S.: Having 'home' in a separate partition, is a good way to prevent system crashes, and to upgrade versions. See [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). I used it to install Ubuntu 12.10 in one notebook, and just to separate partitions in another notebook with 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 2):

```
nano /home/$USER/.xsession-errors
```

At the bottom of .xsessions-errors, it said **permission denied to .ICEauthority** (/home/$USER/.ICEauthority)

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.ICEauthority
```

**The Above fixed the problem.**

The Below messed it up again for me.

```
sudo chmod 0644 /home/$USER/.ICEauthority
```

Its the correct command, but when I rebooted I noticed the owner was changed to 0644 for some [odd reason.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55568/could-not-update-iceauthority-file-after-login-independent-of-gnome/1279297#comment2172996_1279297)

Comment: Since the owner was changed to 0644, you must have run `chown 0644` instead of `chmod 0644`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense... I can see myself making a mistake like that.  Thanks for pointing that out @Zanna!

Comment: :) What's useful about you mentioning that that command didn't help you, is that it shows that only the first command was needed to fix the problem

Comment: What your saying is correct.  I `ls -lh` in the directory before I ran any other commands and the owner was already set to $USER, which is right.  As far as what I did to put myself in this situation... I'm not sure... the only fishy thing I did was change the su/root password.  Other than that, I used my computer like a normal user, updated the OS like a normal user, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem.

It is a file permission problem but don't assume it is .ICEauthority only.
In my case the home folder permissions had changed (how? I do not know)

Took me a while to figure it out because I never expected my home folder permissions
to change.

So your home folders permissions should be 0755 or 0700 or whatever (7 must be a 7 though)
and .ICEauthority should work with 0600
If you need to use 0644 something is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+ALT+F2 at the login window to switch to a vt command line and login there, Then type:
`sudo chown username:username ~/.IceAuthority`

And then type:
`chmod 0600 ~/.IceAuthority`

Hit ALT+F7 to get back to the graphical login window and try to login there

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://www.frapcom.be/mediawiki/index.php/SUN_OpenSolaris#Bug_13534_.22Could_not_update_ICEauthority_file_.2F.ICEauthority.22_on_bootup_build_130_and_above).

> ### Bug 13534 "Could not update ICEauthority file /.ICEauthority" on bootup build 130 and above
>
> After the system boots, the following warning dialog boxes may be
>   displayed:
>
> > **Could not update ICEauthority file /.ICEauthority**
> >
> > There is a problem with the configuration server (/usr/lib/gconf-sanity-check-2
> >     exited with status 256)
>
> **Work-around:**
>   Clicking on the "Close" button for each dialog box will permit one to login normally. 
>   Once logged in, enter the following command to correct the home directory for the "gdm" user
>
> ```
> $ pfexec usermod -d /var/lib/gdm gdm
> ```

---

Edit: Ubuntu uses Lightdm in recent releases instead of GDM.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the user with the home directory addition switch ;)
useradd  -m blah blah blah
Start right, end right.

Answer (score 0):

@daedlanth

That was right. I created a user with useradd and then passwd, I got ICEAuthority error.
Then, I deleted the account, followed all the right steps, logged in and there I got the desktop without any problems!

Steps for your reference (taken from http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/03/03/20-things-installing-kali-linux/)

```
useradd -m user1
passwd user1
usermod -a -G sudo user1
chsh -s /bin/bash user1
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem and cannot login for my user. I tried theses two methods mentioned above 
1- change the premissions
2- delete the iceAuthority file

but still i could not make it so i make a simple move by crating a new user

1. At the login screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to the console.
2. Log in there.
3. create user by addser as describe in this link

here is thread to create user 
[link for creating user by command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto)

and then login with that user.Remember to use adduser as "add useradd command wont create '/home/username' directory but adduser command will"

**conculsion**: This trick will get you your all your data in home/olduser/
**P.S** Need help can we copy new iceAuthority file  (/.ICEauthority) from /home/newuser to home/olduser 
to access previous account

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but I had a somehow related issue (on Debian 10.1), a quick Internet search led me here.

After I created a new user, the home directory had appropriate permissions, and did not contain any `.ICEauthority` file, which is OK so far. I thought it would be generated at first desktop login, but apparently, it's not.

I just created an empty file, as root (replace `username` with your actual username):

```
sudo touch ~username/.ICEauthority
sudo chown username:username ~username/.ICEauthority
sudo chmod 0600 ~username/.ICEauthority
```

It was then generated at first desktop session and everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue as my home directory was deleted. Just recreated the folder, added the default config files, and changed the owner to me:

```
sudo mkdir /home/user
cp -a /etc/skel/* /home/user
chown -R user:user /home/user
```

This is how, I resolved the issue.