# Cannot login as Admin after vsftpd install

Tags: ftp

I have installed vsftpd and did some commands in terminal like 
`chown root:root /home/myusername`. And the next time I started my computer i could not log in as usual. An error message that erupts which says `Could not update ICEauthority`.
PLZ HELP ME I'm stuck with this.
I used [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04) for `vsftpd` install.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Could not update ICEauthority file" after login (independent of gnome)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55568/could-not-update-iceauthority-file-after-login-independent-of-gnome)

Comment: What do you mean by "some commands" was the only one chown? If not what other commands have you run? By default ICEauthority is rw for the user only; which is probably "root" now.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it has the same symptoms, but this is likely caused by changing all the home user owner, not just one file.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start Ubuntu in [safe mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode), then from the terminal issue this command:

```
chown myusername:myusername /home/myusername
```

Change myusername for your actual user name, of course. The problem looks like you make your home dir owned by root.

Comment: Yet another reason for login loop beside the `.Xauthority` and `/tmp`.