# Not able to login to Administrator Account in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could not update ICEauthority file /home/me/.ICEauthority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39785/could-not-update-iceauthority-file-home-me-iceauthority)

I'm using 12.04. It was working fine till now. Suddenly today it happened to stuck/hang. I was writing Python scripts which went in infinite loop. So I restarted my PC and was unable to login to Admin account. I'm writing this, unfortunately, from my Guest account.

I tried many questions but none of them solved my problem.

Tried

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

from Single User Mode, but it says

`No such file or directory`
even when I'm in my home directory

Edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to enable manual login. This didn't work either.

[EDIT] I tried using gdm. When I logged in my Administrator account, it said

```
Could not update .ICEauthority
```

Comment: You should try `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority` under your profile, meaning the prompt should show your home directory before you run that command.

Comment: It says No such file and directory even when I'm in my home directory

Comment: what does logging in via TTY1 result in (CTRL+ALT+F1)?

Comment: Able to login successfully with msg saying
'No Directory, Logging in with HOME=/'

Comment: okay, what does `ls -l` in /home output?

Comment: many lines of which first line is for my admin account

Comment: d-------- admin admin 4096 ...........

Comment: next line for other account has
drwxr-xr-x myaccount myaccount 23

Comment: That's interesting. So the (your) home directory exists, but some programs are complaining that it doesn't. I'm out of ideas. EDIT: As root, `chown -Rfv 755 /home/admin`

Comment: Yeah I'm able to surf to all my directories with root..
Anyways thanks for help

Comment: Just try what I've added into the last comment.