# Ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: installation, login, users

I thought I would try 12.04 installation on a spare laptop still running 10.04 rather than on my main laptop running on 11.10. 
I installed 12.04 over rather than clean.

Fine… But I cannot login as my normal user (only as a guest) so I cannot get benefits of over installation. When I try to login as my user and use my password, I get the following message:

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/username/.ICEauthority
```

Though my password is valid for superuser applications.

Since then I changed the password via the `passwrd` command, but I still get the same error message.

Do you have any suggestions ?
If not I will run a clean installation I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this startup dialog message mean "Could not update ICEauthority file"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10543/what-does-this-startup-dialog-message-mean-could-not-update-iceauthority-file)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and just fixed it.

The main problem I had was when upgrading I used the same user id as before. But Ubuntu actually created a new user and associated the home directory to my previous users folder. As a result all my old files were associated with my older user id and was not accessible to my new ip.

So doing a `chown` should fix it:

```
sudo chown -R user:group ~/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to login as root from the grub screen if you can get working (if it doesn't normally show, do left shift during boot).  It should be possible to reset the password for your account from the root terminal once you have it.  Just thought; when you say 'installed over' ... you didn't use wubi did you?

Comment: no no wubi just installed after looking at live cd trial..I can login but not as myself

Comment: Update..so I changed the password via the cammand passwrd ..Still same message...could not update ICEauthority file /home/username/.ICEauthority

Answer (score 0):

- Switch to the text console `[Ctrl][Alt][F1]`
- Login with your username / password
- Check for errors, write them down word for word. Did you enter your home directory?
- Check the output for `ls -l /home`. Does it say `drwx` at the start of the line, notice especially the `w`?
- Check for nearly full filesystems `df -h`
- Type `exit`
- Switch to the graphics console `[Ctrl][Alt][F7]`
- If you had any errors on the text console, add them to your question.

Comment: Hi you mean looking for errors after I login?...Nope none

Comment: Do the other checks too, copy the output in your question.

Comment: I did.Seems all ok.The fact is there appears to be no .ICEauthority file

Comment: What is the output to `mount`? Copy it to your question. Same for `ls -l /home /username /home/username/.ICEauthority`