# Error "Could not update ICEauthority file" while using the vmware 

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on the vmware player . However, all of a sudden I got the error "could not update ICEAuthority file" when I tried to boot.

I tried looking up a load of solutions but all of those involved getting into the command line while booting, but I can't get into the command line in the virtual machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get into the login screen, that is the screen which ask for password?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What was the last thing you did or the last command you executed? Does it have anything to do with file permissions in your home folder?

Comment: Please see the following link for answer

http://askubuntu.com/questions/132132/ubuntu-12-04-installation/212195#212195