# Login screen looping after installing CUDA ToolKit on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, xorg, login, cuda

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - 32 bit version on my system. I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. I installed the following packages -

1. vim-gnome,
2. python-matplotlib,
3. python-scipy,
4. acroread, and
5. git.

I have a GPU on my machine: Nvidia GeForce GT 520. I wanted to install the CUDA Toolkit on this machine. For this, I have followed the instructions given in the webpage

https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs344/ubuntu_dev

I did what has been told there with few changes:

1. In the step `sudo apt-get install build-essential libopencv-dev linux-headers-uname -r`(I dind't put `uname -r` in the appropriate quotes to maintain consistency), I have skipped the installation of `libopencv-dev` because I wanted to install OpenCV separately.
2. I have downloaded the 32-bit version of CUDA Toolkit from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads.
3. I have stopped the lightdm service in the beginning of the installation using the command `sudo service lightdm stop`.
4. The entire installation was done using the command prompt (`CTRL-ALT-F1`).

After this, when I tried to login from my account, I am unable to login. Though I am entering the correct password, it is returning me to the login screen. I have tried to do the following:

1. Used the command `sudo chown <myusername>:<myyusername> .Xauthority` from the command prompt. But, it showed an error that `Could not update ICE authority file /home/user/.ICEauthority`
2. So, I followed the procedure on [Cannot login after update ubuntu 12.04 . ICEauthority error message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356284/cannot-login-after-update-ubuntu-12-04-iceauthority-error-message). It still didn't work.
3. I tried to remove the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` which was made during the installation as given above. I then updated: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Waiting for an answer.

Comment: I am able to use the guest account.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to this problem.

A short and easy procedure to install CUDA Tool kit v5.5 in Ubuntu is given on this link:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVzSullC9l8

If you have any version of CUDA, then run this command: `/usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall`. Then, proceed with the installation. The Xorg settings, and blacklisting drivers are automatically taken care of during the installation. I have followed this procedure and I could easily install CUDA on my machine.